# What are the application of result "Every compact metric space is separable"?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness, separable-spaces

What are the application of result "**Every compact metric space is separable**"?

I wanted to do some exrecise problem which uses the result **Every compact metric space is separable** so that I can understand the result upto the fullest.

Please suggest some exercise problems...

Thank you

Comment: Show that if $X$ is a metric compact space, $C(X,\mathbb{R})$ is separable.

Comment: @MindlackI don't think that has anything to do with the quoted theorem. Weierstraß rather.

Answer (score 3):

The result has as immediate consequence that a compact non-separable space is not metrisable, so e.g. $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ in the order topology induced by the lexicographic order (the lexicographically ordered square) is not metrisable.

Comment: As another example of the same kind, we also get a proof (maybe not the most direct one...) that metrizability is not preserved under products.

Comment: @ChrisEagle Using separability we need $\mathfrak{c}^+$ many factors, while using an altermative fact for metric spaces, $w(X)=d(X)$, we can reduce this to $\aleph_1$ many factors, so that argument is more efficient.

Comment: Yes, I agree completely (hence the parenthetical remark in my comment).  I was just pointing out this was a thing one could deduce from the theorem the poster was talking about.